# WL 6.1 mobilewebapp version in application-descriptor.xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I see from the documentation that the version attribute for the mobilewebapp environment has been removed? Why is this? Is there any way to add this? This was very useful for us!

Using WL 6.1.0.01.20140418-0637.

Comment: if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand how it was "useful" to you, because this property never had any actual meaning for the Mobile Web and/or Desktop we browser environments to begin with. It only caused confusion, hence it is now removed.

There is no way to add it back by the developer.

If you think it is useful to you for some reason, you can submit a feature request: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/connect.html